# How Can I avoid a Indefinite Loop While Searching a string from a no of files

Tags: perl

In my below program, I was trying to search a string from no of files In a folder but output Is printing in continuous manner rather than stopping after required search. Can some one pls help to point out the error ?
i.e. I am trying to Search the string "VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER" from @files but I am not getting the desired output but I am getting repetitive output of my strings.

```
# #!/usr/bin/perl
# use strict; 
use warnings;

&IMS_Compare_Message();
sub IMS_Compare_Message
{

    print "Entering the value i.e. the IMS Message to compare with";
    my $value = '';
    my $choice = '';
    my $loop = '';

  print "\nThe script path & name is $0\n";
  print "\nPlease enter desired number to select any of the following   


    (1) Start Comparing REGISTER message !!

    (2) Start Comparing SUBSCRIBE message

        (3) Start Comparing INVITE message \n";

    $value = <STDIN>;

    if ($value == 1 )
    {

        print "\n Start Comparing REGISTER message\n\n";
        $IMS_Message = "VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER";
        #chomp ($IMS_Message);
    }

    elsif ($value == 2)
    {

        print "\n SUBSCRIBE message Flow\n\n";


    }
    elsif ($value == 3)
    {

        print "\n INVITE message Flow\n\n";


    }
    else 
    {
        print "\nThe input is not valid!\n";
        print "\nDo you want to continue selecting a Automation Mode again (Y or N)?\n";

        $choice = <STDIN>;
        if( $choice =~ /[Yy]/) {        
            test_loop();
        } else {
            exit;
        }
    }

my $kw = "$IMS_Message";
my @files = grep {-f} (<*main_log>);

foreach my $file (@files) 
{
    open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
    my @content = <$fh>;
    close($fh);
    my $l = 0;
    $search = chomp ($kw);
    #my $search = quotemeta($kw);
        foreach (@content) 
            { # go through every line for this keyword
                $l++;
                if (/$search/)
                    {
                        printf 'Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d:%s'.$/, $kw, $file, $l, $_
                    }
            }
}
}
```

After Modificaiton

```
# #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings;


    print "Entering the value i.e. the IMS Message to compare with";
    my $value = '';
    my $choice = '';
    my $loop = '';
    my $IMS_Message = '';
    my $search = '';
    my $kw = '';

    print "\nThe script path & name is $0\n";
    print "\nPlease enter desired number to select any of the following   

    (1) Start Comparing REGISTER message !!
    (2) Start Comparing SUBSCRIBE message
        (3) Start Comparing INVITE message \n";

    $value = <STDIN>;

    if ($value == 1 )
    {

        print "\n Start Comparing REGISTER message\n\n";
        $IMS_Message = "VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER";
        #chomp ($IMS_Message);
    }

    elsif ($value == 2)
    {

        print "\n SUBSCRIBE message Flow\n\n";


    }
    elsif ($value == 3)
    {

        print "\n INVITE message Flow\n\n";


    }
    else 
    {
        print "\nThe input is not valid!\n";
        print "\nDo you want to continue selecting a Automation Mode again (Y or N)?\n";

        $choice = <STDIN>;
        if( $choice eq /[Yy]/) {        
            test_loop();
        } else {
            exit;
        }


    $kw = $IMS_Message;
    $search = qr/\Q$kw/;

    for my $file ( grep { -f } glob '*main_log' ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        if ( /$search/ ) {
            printf "Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d: %s\n", $kw, $file, $., $_;
            last;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The title and question are saying different things. It's quite unclear with what you want help. (And this: `# use strict;` Don't do that!)

Comment: `chomp` doesn't return what you think it does. (And what is it doing nowhere near a `<>`?)

Comment: I just removed the chomp but still It;s same output

Comment: The whole point of `use strict` is that it generates error messages that guide you towards basic errors in your code. Failing to add `use strict` is wrong, but to write it and then comment it out is completely foolish, as you are saying that you want to keep all of those mistakes. It is ridiculous to ask the whole world for help with your code when you have chosen to ignore the basic aid built into Perl itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some observations on your code

- Your approach to debugging appears to be to try things at random to see if they work. It would be far more fruitful to add diagnostic `print` statements so that you can compare variables' actual values with what you expect

  Error and warning messages are useful information, and it is foolish to comment out `use strict` to make them go away
- Don't call subroutines with an ampersand `&`. That hasn't been best practice for twenty years now
- Lay your code out tidily and cinsistently, so that both you and any people you ask for help can read it easily. As it stands it is impossible to tell where blocks start and end without counting brace characters `{...}`
- Variables should be declared with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use, and not all at once at the top of the file or subroutine
- `chomp` is necessary only for strings that have been read from the terminal or from a file. It returns the *number of characters removed*, not the trimmed string
- `if( $choice =~ /[Yy]/ ) { ... }` will check only whether the string *contains* a `Y`, so if the operator enters `MARRY ME!` it will return *true*. You should use string equality `eq` to check whether a single `Y` character has been typed
- You shouldn't put scalar variables alone inside double quotes. At best it will make no difference, and just add noise to your code; at worst it will completely change the value of the variable. Just `my $kw = $IMS_Message` is correct
- Unless you require non-sequential access to the contents of a file, it is best to use a `while` loop to read and process it line by line, rather than read the whole thing into an array and process each element of the array. This also allows you to use the built-in line number variable `$.` instead of implementing your own `$l`

The main problem is that you have derived `$search` from the result of `chomp $kw`, which sets `$search` to the number of characters removed by chomp. This is always zero because `$kw` is a copy of `$IMS_Message`, which has no newline at the end. That means you are checking all the lines of every file for  the character `0`, and not for the message that you intended. The correct way is `my $search = quotemeta($kw)` which you had in place but have commented out, presumably as a result of your policy of "debugging by guesswork"

Fixing these things, your code should look something like this

```
my $search = qr/\Q$kw/;

for my $file ( grep { -f } glob '*main_log' ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        if ( /$search/ ) {
            printf "Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d: %s\n", $kw, $file, $., $_;
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Borodin.. Thanks for guiding . I did the modifications you suggested but still I am not getting any output I want .. I get no output at all . I have added the code above.

Comment: @rocky: Please open a new question and show your full code, together with a short sample data file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Opened a new question with Title - Unable to Search string from multiple files In a particular directory. thanks